# Can Blu-ray discs be played from a Mac if you aren't using HDMI?

Tags: mac, hdmi, blu-ray

I'm using a Dell Ultrasharp monitor connected using Display Port (it *doesn't* have HDMI, it *does* have DVI and VGA). It's connected to a Mac Mini using the thunderbolt connector.

(Note the Mac Mini *does* have HDMI, but I have no way of using it with the display.)

I'm considering getting an external blu-ray player, assuming I can find a reliable enough brand - but does the lack of HDMI mean it'll be impossible to play discs? I read that during the (lengthy?) load sequence the player does a check on the security of the output.

(I'm not concerned about 4K as the monitor is only a 24" 1920x1200, just the improvement from SD to HD).

Comment: Regular Blu-Ray is only 'HD' 1k anyway. 'Ultra HD Blu-Ray' is 4k & requires a specific player type. idk about the security aspect, sorry.

Comment: Look at [this](https://appletoolbox.com/how-to-play-a-blu-ray-on-your-mac/) : Blu-ray is not natively supported on Mac but you can use third party softwares.